# Aurelia validation on dynamically created form

Tags: aurelia

I was able to get Aurelia-validation working on a dynamically created form when using the compose element, but I've switched to custom elements for better encapsulation and reuse of the custom controls.  However, now my validation seems to be half-broken.

https://gist.run/?id=6e97538c3888cae0f6134faed9d67362

**Issue 1:** The ValidateBindingBehavior is not doing anything.  I suspect it's not finding the controller or matching the rules since the property name is not easily visible in the binding (due to dynamic controls).

**Issue 2:** For some reason `validate()` on submit actually only shows the first error instead of all of them.  That indicates a problem but I don't know what.

Can anyone get the attached GistRun to work properly?

Comment: Isn't there a way to specify validation rules as JSON?

Comment: Not that I am aware of... but if there is, it would make my life easier!

Comment: I just asked in the team chat room. I remember Jeremy or Patrick telling me there is a way to do it at some point.

Comment: Ok, here's what I found. This blog post on our blog: http://blog.aurelia.io/2016/09/09/json-schema-validation/ which links to a gist.run example which is a bit out of date. I've updated it (it's not production ready yet, but you can start from this): https://gist.run/?id=c16b738fc2dabfa39ec4415bef244654

Comment: I think it would be possible to build a class that can take a properly constructed JSON object and build out a set of validation rules. I'm gonna play with that for a bit. I'm supposed to be doing other stuff right now, but this is more fun.

Comment: BOOM! https://gist.run/?id=6f3a0c1522f41bf2915a8c22d7098bd9 I made it happen.

Comment: This is great!  I'll try to implement it tomorrow.  Thanks as always for your help, even if it was a distraction from more important and boring things.